# Why is there a difference regarding lifetime elision of impl trait function arguments between async and non-async functions?

Tags: rust, lifetime

This code compiles:

```rust
async fn foo(_: impl Iterator<Item = &u32>) {}
```

However, removing the `async`, it does not work anymore:

```rust
fn foo(_: impl Iterator<Item = &u32>) {}
```

Instead, it results in:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/lib.rs:1:32
  |
1 | fn foo(_: impl Iterator<Item = &u32>) {}
  |                                ^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
1 | fn foo<'a>(_: impl Iterator<Item = &'a u32>) {}
  |       ^^^^                         ^^^
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1600f9f8c737e04c38e05c2a6348333f))

Why is there a difference regarding lifetime elision between `async` and non-`async` functions? This makes no sense to me. It seems like the non-`async` case could easily leave out the lifetime as well. It's just introducing another anonymous input lifetime.

Comment: I doubt there is any profound reason for it. Much like `Box<dyn Trait>` and `impl Trait` have different elision behavior for (IMO) no good reason.

Comment: Mhh, now I wonder if that's even intended or whether it's an oversight/bug?

Comment: I [asked on the issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/85417) now.